# How to create a facebook event on users behalf using javascript sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I'm trying to piece together information and different chunks of code scattered throughout the documentation on how to make this happen, since there aren't good examples. 
I know I have to first get the create_event extended permission which I get with this code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'create_event'})
```

;

I know that I also have to issue a HTTP POST request to 'PROFILE_ID/events' with the create_event permissions and the necessary parameters. 
My problems are:  1. I don't know how to collect the create_event permission once it is given. If I run the code above, a dialog box will open asking for the permission but once I accept, only a blank page follows. 
2. If everything works the way it supposed to with the permissions request and the post request, will my app see a create event page like I would if I were to create an event on my own from my profile? What interface gets seen from the app? Can I take a user from my app directly to the facebook create event page?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/ is a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I don't know how to collect the create_event permission once it is given. If I run the code above, a dialog box will open asking for the permission but once I accept, only a blank page follows.

That’s how it works. Everything you want to show to the user after successful login, you have to implement yourself.

> 1. If everything works the way it supposed to with the permissions request and the post request, will my app see a create event page like I would if I were to create an event on my own from my profile? What interface gets seen from the app?

No “interface” at all – it’s up to you to build that.

> Can I take a user from my app directly to the facebook create event page?

The user can go their by themselves. Why would the need your app for that?

Comment: My app is meant to help create a specific TYPE of event. I'm trying to use the facebook event object to expedite the process of building invite functionality in my app. That's the point of this. What I should have also asked about is what the permission actually looks like. Is it a long number like the access token that I have to store in a variable? How do locate the granted permission so I can pass it to the api? I haven't come across anything in the documentation that explains this enough, maybe I'm over looking something, but if there's a link someone can provide it'd be helpful.

Comment: Permissions are handled on Facebook’s side, all you need to do is pass your access token to the API.